# Cordova ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs' Error

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

````
```> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
````

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libnode.so'. If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#automatic_packaging_of_prebuilt_dependencies_used_by_cmake

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BU?LD FAILED in 20s
41 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 38 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\Privat\Desktop\FamilienPunkte\fp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\Privat\Desktop\FamilienPunkte\fp\platforms\android\build.gradle```

> **Im using nodejs-mobile-cordova and cordova-plugin-console plugins.**
> Ty for helping!

Comment: Did you find a soluation ?